# Sorting result based on the date by year followed by month in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query to group and show results in Month_yeat and count format.

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR (D_DATE,
    'MON')

         || '_'

         || TO_CHAR (D_DATE,
    'YYYY') Month_Year,
    COUNT (*) Request_Count
FROM
    MY_TABLE WHERE V_TYPE='ABCD'
GROUP BY
    TO_CHAR (D_DATE,
    'MON') || '_' || TO_CHAR (D_DATE,
    'YYYY')
    
ORDER BY
    1;
```

I require the output should be sorted based on the year first then month.
eg:
The current output is :

```
MAR_2023    2223
FEB_2023    433
MAY_2022    10
APR_2022    77
```

Required output is :

```
FEB_2023    433
MAR_2023    2223
APR_2022    77
MAY_2022    10
```

I know that this is sorting based on alphabetical if i give the condition in order by, but need a solution which can solve this problem
Note : grouping year and month as separate column and sorting on it is not acceptable.

Comment: *grouping year and month as separate column and sorting on it is not acceptable* - so please clarify which manipulations are acceptable. The easiest solution would be to group by `trunc(d_date, 'mm')`, put it in the `order by` and place `to_char(trunc(...), 'MON-YYYY')` in the select list

Answer (score 1):

You can, but with additional part of `group by` and `order by` clause, e.g.

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR (D_DATE, 'MON') || '_' || TO_CHAR (D_DATE, 'YYYY') Month_Year,
         COUNT (*) Request_Count
    FROM MY_TABLE
   WHERE V_TYPE = 'ABCD'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (D_DATE, 'MON') || '_' || TO_CHAR (D_DATE, 'YYYY'),
         TO_CHAR (d_date, 'yyyymm')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR (d_date, 'yyyymm')
```

- `order by` will make sure that rows are correctly sorted
- `group by` then requires it as well (otherwise you'll get "
  ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" error)

Answer (score 0):

Truncate the date to the start of the month and group by that then order by the truncated date and not the formatted string.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(D_DATE, 'MM'), 'MON_YYYY') Month_Year,
       COUNT (*) Request_Count
FROM   MY_TABLE
WHERE  V_TYPE='ABCD'
GROUP BY TRUNC(D_DATE, 'MM')
ORDER BY TRUNC(D_DATE, 'MM');
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (v_type, d_date) AS
SELECT 'ABCD', DATE '2022-01-01' + LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 19 UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCD', DATE '2023-01-01' + LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCD', DATE '2023-02-01' + LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCD', DATE '2023-03-01' + LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  7;
```

Outputs:

| MONTH_YEAR | REQUEST_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| JAN_2022 | 19 |
| JAN_2023 | 12 |
| FEB_2023 | 5 |
| MAR_2023 | 7 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q9EHFbSe)

Comment: This is a prod data. I cannot do truncate

Comment: @ShanijP.S Please read the [`TRUNC`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html) documentation. You are **NOT** changing the data stored in the tables you are applying a function to a column just like using `TO_CHAR`. I think you are getting confused between the `TRUNC` function and [`TRUNCATE TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TRUNCATE-TABLE.html) which is a DDL statement and not a function.

Comment: @ShanijP.S also note that `select` statement is a read-only statement and it has no any side-effects unless it uses functions with `pragma autonomous_transaction`. It technically cannot modify anything.